# Convert UTC to Local

Tags: jquery, date

I have a UTC date like this: `01-01-1969 00:00:00`. I want to convert it to local time using jQuery. I have tried the below, but it completely messes up the format.

```
var date = new Date('01-01-1969 00:00:00 UTC');
date.toString()
```

and also

```
var date = new Date('26-04-1973 00:00:00 UTC');//gives invalid date
```

this gives an invalid date. Strange, infact there are many more date which returns invalid date.

Comment: What you have will work fine, but you will need to format it yourself in JS. I would suggest using a library for it, such as DateJS.

Comment: I don't want any more libraries for that

Comment: In that case you will need to build the string yourself using the date methods JS has. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more information

Comment: can you tell me why var date = new Date('26-04-1973 00:00:00 UTC'); this give invalid date @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Because the string passed to `Date()` should be in American date format, ie `MM-DD-YYYY`: http://jsfiddle.net/xv6ywoht/

Comment: thnks a lot. it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93500/discussion-between-furquan-khan-and-rory-mccrossan).